# should I submit a proposal to a job just to catch the job then look for solutions?

Tags: freelance-websites, group-freelancing

I'm a developer and I feel like an imposter whenever I read a job description. I know that I can solve the problems, but I take time to search for the terms in the job description before submitting it, which makes me lose many jobs. should I submit a proposal to a job just to catch the job then look for solutions.

Comment: This question is not clear. Are you saying that you do not know the English terms and have to translate them into your own language or are you saying that you do not know the what the technical meaning of those terms are and are looking up code that others have written to that term?

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand what the client wants and I try to search for a better understanding, but from what I see other freelancers don't even read the job description and they just submitted their proposals and try to figure out what the client wants after they get accepted for the job @DavidR   the site is upwork and its my first ever time trying to work as online freekancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, people who post projects on UpWork get many proposals (between 50-100 on some projects) and they have to quickly figure out which proposals to toss away. Those that appear to be "standard proposals" often get tossed first. Adding your "standard proposal" to the pile of "toss this quickly" is not a good way to get projects.

The purpose of a proposal on UpWork is to get an interview. What I do is to look for projects where I know I can solve them, but also bring extra experience to bear that would help the business owner. I'll spend a good bit of time writing up why my business is a good match for the project description. On UpWork, my goal is one good proposal a week. I want the proposal to really address the concerns and show that I can solve the problems. (That is because so many projects are simply technical skill descriptions which someone else can do cheaper.) It can take six to nine months to get a project this way. But, I look for high value projects that are worth waiting for.

Someone who posts a project will interview four to ten people for that project. It is in the interview where we actually make the sale. Odds are that it can take 5-10 interviews to get a project.

It is best to not worry about what other people send in as their proposals. Those will get tossed quickly. Instead, my advice is to focus on making the best proposal you can. Try to think of what the person who posted the project really wants and offer a solution to their problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.ill try to  improve my communication skills to get better chances